# How do I unlock all the cut scenes in the theater archive on Proud Mode?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep, kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

**Important Note:**
I cannot stress enough that this question is about KH: Birth by Sleep Final Mix (as released in KH HD 2.5 Remix in 2014) since all my online searches yield results for the non final mix version released in 2010 and the conditions for unlocking bonus features has changed.

**Question:**
How do I unlock all the cut scenes in the theater archive? I am playing on Proud mode.

What I have done:

- Completed all character stories on Proud mode
- Collected and used all stickers in the journal
- Opened all chests
- Completed final episode

What I have unlocked in the theater archive:

- Terra (all Terra story cut scenes)
- Ventus (all Ventus story cut scenes)
- Aqua (all Aqua story cut scenes)
- Final Episode (all cut scenes in the playable Final Episode)
- Where the Heart goes

The theater archive says there are two more cut scenes that I have not unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that collecting and using all the stickers for each character story was not enough. You score points based on where you place each sticker and I had not earned enough points.

You can read more about the sticker albums and points on the Kingdom Hearts wikia site: http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Sticker_Album